# My Ghostscript no output file

Tags: ghostscript

My ghostscript has no output file and I dont know why. Below is a screenshot:
[image]

Help is much appreciated. Thanks

Comment: The first thing to say is **upgrade**. 8.71 is 6 years old, the current version is 9.19. Other than that, there's nothing that can be said from a screenshot (especially one which doesn't even provide the entire transcript), you will need to provide an example file.

Comment: hi @KenS  the above exact script works on the latest version of Ghostscript but not on 8.71. The thing is I need to run this script on a server not owned by me, my hands are tied getting them to upgrade their Ghostscript version.

Comment: You haven't supplied any script. I assume you mean that the input file works as expected on a recent version, which likely means a bug was fixed (you haven't supplied an example so its impossible to tell). If you can't upgrade the software then you are stuck, there is nowhere to go from there.

Comment: Okay thanks @KenS for the input. Yes it is working as expected on the newest version of GS.